# Version conflict with a dll

Tags: dll, umbraco, nopcommerce

I am developing an mvc application that uses Umbraco and NopCommerce.

Umbraco depends on dll called AutoMapper.dll with version 3.0.0.0.
NopCommerce depends on the same dll but with version 3.3.1.0.

So when I add the dll with version 3.0.0.0 then NopCommerce crashes.
When I add the dll with version 3.3.1.0 then Umbraco crashes.

So i somehow need to use the same dll with two different versions.

I have tried to add something like below to the web.config file:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="AutoMapper" publicKeyToken="be96cd2c38ef1005" culture="neutral"/>
    <codeBase version="3.0.0.0" href="F:\Visual Studio test projects\UmbracoTest\UmbracoTest\bin\AutoMapper3000\AutoMapper.dll"/>
    <codeBase version="3.3.1.0" href="F:\Visual Studio test projects\UmbracoTest\UmbracoTest\bin\AutoMapper3310\AutoMapper3310\AutoMapper.dll"/>
  </dependentAssembly>
```

But with no luck.

Have anyone been in the same situation? Any advice on how to solve this?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

No such luck, Umbraco simply doesn't support Automapper versions > 3.0. See [this recent tweet conversation](https://twitter.com/j_breuer/status/641720409818296320). How tied to NopCommerce are you? There are other options specifically for Umbraco, like [Merchello](http://merchello.com) or [uCommerce](http://www.ucommerce.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Hmm i guess i must start search for another commerce solution than nopcommerce :). Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: You CAN force uninstall automapper using NuGet and use a newer version, however some Umbraco packages (such as Archetype) will not work.